# Black hole wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, wavefunction

Does a black hole have a wave function? Matter falling into a black hole has a wave function. Is the wave function of this matter destroyed or converted to information on the surface of the black hole? Does the information on the surface of the black hole have a wave function?

Comment: These are too many questions at once. It is generally best to try to ask one question at a time.

Comment: The short answer to all questions however is, "we don't know". The answers to these questions are intimately related to the open physics problem known as the "black hole information paradox"

Comment: Does your bicycle have one? The sun? The galaxy? The universe?

Comment: I agree that there were many questions, but they were intimately related. I am very interested in the "black hole paradox", Thank you Andrei for the references. Cosmas, I believe that my bicycle has a wave function, or created by one, as are the other items you mentioned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Karpinsky,

There is a series of papers by Gerard ’t Hooft available on arxiv where he discusses the quantum description of black holes, information paradox, etc. Few links below:

The quantum black hole as a theoretical lab, a pedagogical treatment of a new approach
https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.10469

Discreteness of Black Hole Microstates
https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.05367

What happens in a black hole when a particle meets its antipode
https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.01383

The firewall transformation for black holes and some of its implications
https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08640

The Quantum Black Hole as a Hydrogen Atom: Microstates Without Strings Attached
https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.05119

I think you may find some answers there.

Comment: It should be noted that 't Hooft's views on the subject aren't exactly mainstream. (Which does not mean that he is wrong.)

Comment: What is the mainstream view?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a *the* mainstream for this. However mainstream discussion has recently mostly focused on solutions involving entanglement entropy, AdS/CFT, and/or firewalls.

Comment: Yes, but those mainstream discussions were in a context of a theory (string theory) that is not nearly as established as the standard model that 't Hooft uses. AdS/CFT is not even about our universe so it is not directly relevant to the question. Anyway, if you know papers that better address the question it would be nice to link them here.

Comment: -1. Link-only answers become useless if the link [rots away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), so while this may theoretically answer the question, please include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers are [not considered answers](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/859/168783) here and will be deleted.